# How to return Specific Class types without a large Select/Switch

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I'm building a series of classes in an attempt to reduce the manual coding of specific class types from the mainline code.

Whichever way I look there is always somewhere that requires manual coding of the specific class type.

I was hoping that I could use reflection/activator etc to be able to use the work done in the constructor to be able to return the classtypes (of the correct type) without needing to do the large (although the example here has been reduced) select/switch statement that is in `GetPacket`.

I know this is VB.Net, but the project was already written in that language, I don't mind if you post C# examples I'll just convert them.
But please don't retag as a VB.Net question because it's not about language it's about how to do it within the framework.

```
Imports ProtoBuf

Public Class CompatiblePackets
    Inherits Dictionary(Of Packet.PacketType, Base)

    Public Sub New()
        Dim theAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
        For Each t As Type In theAssembly.GetTypes
            If t.BaseType Is GetType(Base) Then
                Dim p As Base = CType(t.Assembly.CreateInstance(t.FullName), Base)
                Me.Add(p.PacketTypeIndicator, p)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function GetPacket(id As PacketType, data As Stream) As Base
        Dim activePacket As Base
        If Me.ContainsKey(id) Then
            activePacket = Me(id)
        Else
            activePacket = Me(PacketType.Generic)
        End If
        Try
            Select Case id
                Case PacketType.AcknowledgeBulk
                    Return GetPacket(Of AcknowledgeBulk)(activePacket, data)
                Case PacketType.Generic
                    Return GetPacket(Of Generic)(activePacket, data)
                Case PacketType.Identification
                    Return GetPacket(Of Identification)(activePacket, data)

    '''There are so far about 20 more packet types in the real code.

                Case Else
                    'unknown type "Computer says No!"
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            If data.GetType Is GetType(MemoryStream) Then
                Debug.Print(Core.Text.OutputData(CType(data, MemoryStream).ToArray))
            End If
            Throw
        End Try
        Debug.Print("Wtf - " & id.ToString())

        Return New NoOperation
    End Function

    Private Function GetPacket(Of t)(activePacket As Packet.Base, data As Stream) As t
        Return Serializer.Deserialize(Of t)(data)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it looks like you should be using `Serializer.NonGeneric`; this has various methods for passing the `Type` in manually and without using generics, including `Serialize` and `Deserialize`.

Note that for this scenario, `Serializer.NonGeneric` also has a specific API for heterogeneous header-marked messages, which you may find useful for a network-stream scenario:

```
static void Main() {
    // memory-stream only for example - would work fine with NetworkStream too
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        // this is just to simulate an incoming network-stream
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Foo { Name = "abc" },
           PrefixStyle.Base128, 1); // tag 1 for Foo
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Bar { Value = 123 },
           PrefixStyle.Base128, 2); // tag 2 for Bar
        ms.Position = 0;

        // now we'll consume it

        //first setup some map of 1=Foo, 2=Bar - any mechanism will suffice
        var typeMap = new Dictionary<int, Type>{
            {1, typeof(Foo)},
            {2, typeof(Bar)}
        };
        Serializer.TypeResolver resolver = i => {
            Type type;
            return typeMap.TryGetValue(i, out type) ? type : null;
        };
        object obj;
        while(Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
            ms, PrefixStyle.Base128,resolver,out obj))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("<EOF>");

    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return "Foo: " + Name; }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Bar {
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return "Bar: " + Value; }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Foo: abc
Bar: 123
<EOF>
```

In v2, note that `TypeModel` exposes the non-generic API as the primary interface (the `Serializer` API simply acts as a proxy to the default model).

Comment: this works perfectly, because Protobuf hides all the complexities away, I'm guessing if I wanted to do this with something else Reflection.Emit is where I have to look?

Comment: @Paul it depends on how often it changes, and *when* it changes; another option, for example, is to write a tool you run at build-time that spits out C# based on the current configuration, and just build/deploy that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think your only option is a delightful hodgepodge of reflection goodness:

```
Private Function GetPacket(oPacketType As PacketType, data As Stream) As Base

    Dim oDeserializeMethod As System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    Dim oGenericMethod As System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    Dim oType As Type

    ' Fetch the System.Type for the current packet type. 
    ' This assumes that the enum and the class names are the same
    oType = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType(oPacketType.ToString)

    ' Fetch the deserialize method from Protobuf Serializer
    oDeserializeMethod = GetType(Serializer).GetMethod("Deserialize")

    ' Create a generic method from the deserialize method
    oGenericMethod = oDeserializeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(oType)

    ' And finally, invoke the method
    Return TryCast(oGenericMethod.Invoke(Serializer, Data), Base)
End Function
```

Then you could call this without a need for a case statement:

```
Return GetPacket(id, data)
```

Comment: Not necessary; there is a non-generic API for protobuf-net (in fact, in v2 the **primary** API is non-generic)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Ok, that's good to know. At least it was a good learning experience for me to put together this example. That's why I love this site.

Comment: Actually - another tip: if you are using 4.0 there's a cute trick where you use "dynamic" to do the switch-over, instead of MakeGenericMethod; it is much faster

Comment: Excellent! I will take a look at that as well.

Comment: Here you go: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-dynamic-to-simplify-reflection.html